# Build and train BERT from scratch on my own vocab with Masked Language Modeling MLM

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I d like to build a Bert model MLM from scratch without using Bert-tockenizer, I have my own vocab
(which looks like gibberish: "xddccfff988, 9900zxzxxx, zzzTzz"). At the end, I d like to get embeddings of these gibberish words too.

I v been struggling with this for days and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Saeed, Welcome to SO ;)
I refer you to the official [Huggingface's](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling) repo which includes a lot of comprehensive tutorials and examples. I also recommend reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: you're going to need massive amounts of data and compute fyi